# How to avoid the --app option with heroku CLI?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I'm tired of entering the name of my app each time I run a `heroku` command in the terminal:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app myapp
heroku run rake db:seed --app myapp
heroku run rake sth:else --app myapp
```

The `--app` is very redundant and annoying, I didn't figured out where were the option to configure it globally **once** for the project.

Comment: Please run `git remote -v`. Each Git remote will have two URLs: one for pushing and one for fetching. How many Heroku remotes do you see?

Comment: Yes I have to, both related to github, not heroku.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`heroku` doesn't require the `--app` argument when it knows which app it should talk to. This occurs when there is exactly one Git remote pointing to Heroku for a repository.

You don't appear to have any remotes pointing to Heroku. Run

```
heroku git:remote --app myapp
```

to [add such a remote](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-git-remote). Once that's done you should be able to omit the `--app` argument for `heroku` commands on that particular repository.

If you prefer to do this yourself you can run

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:myapp.git
```

Note that it's possible to have *multiple* Heroku remotes, e.g. if you have a staging and a production app. In this case you will also have to provide the `--app` argument to specify which one should be used.