# How to add -a -app in my Websockets file?

Tags: heroku

I've got a problem when I upload my project on Heroku. I've trying changing value of socket.io and MongoUrl, but I get this error:

```
Error: Missing required flag:
›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with any of your files. It's an argument that you must provide to the Heroku CLI itself, e.g.

```
heroku config:set SOME_VARIABLE=some_value -a myapp
```

where `myapp` is the name of your Heroku app.

The `-a` / `--app` argument is required when `heroku` can't figure out what app to connect to, either bcause there is *no* Heroku remote configured or because there is more than one Heroku remote configured.

See also [How to avoid the --app option with heroku CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55470675/354577)

Comment: Thank you Chris for your answer the command worked successfully, but then i deployed again my app it hadn't been working