# Heroku CLI gives "No Redis instances found" yet I have a redis cloud addon running and usable

Tags: heroku, redis

I'm learning redis and have it working from a java app. I'm trying to use the `heroku redis:cli -a myAppName` command to connect with it directly but it says "No Redis instances found".

When I do `heroku apps` it lists `myAppName` so I know it's valid.

`heroku redis:info -a myAppName` doesn't return anything.

The heroku docs don't seem to be accurate as they all leave out the `-a` flag which the cli tells me is required. Outside of that I don't know what I've missed.

Comment: "The heroku docs don't seem to be accurate as they all leave out the `-a` flag which the cli tells me is required"—this is listed in [most of the docs I've seen](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands) (look in the options for each subcommand), though it [isn't always required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55470675/354577).

Comment: "yet I have a redis cloud addon running and usable"—how did you provision this?

Comment: For example https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-redis-using-cli#redis-info doesn't work as documented. I have to include an -a argument. As for how I provisioned, I don't know how to answer. I setup a free tier 30MB redis cloud db and named it. I've been able to connect to it and use it successfully from a java app.

Comment: "I have to include an -a argument"—only if the CLI can't infer the app to use. I guess they don't always show it, but it often isn't required. See the link in my comment. That argument is sort of a global argument for `heroku`, not specific to any subcommand.

Comment: "I setup a free tier 30MB redis cloud db and named it"—can you say more about this? How did you set it up? Specifically, what do you mean by "redis cloud"? [This](https://redis.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/overview/)?

Comment: Yes, apparently it's the redis enterprise cloud addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at documentation for [Heroku Redis](https://www.heroku.com/redis), a hosted Redis service that Heroku itself provides. If you wish to use Heroku Redis, you can [provision it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#provisioning-the-add-on) for your app using like so:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev -a your-app-name
```

[Pricing for Heroku Redis can be found here](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis#pricing). The Hobby Dev plan used in the previous command is free.

There are also [other Redis providers that can be provisioned this way](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores), including [Redis Enterprise Cloud](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rediscloud). Or you can use existing hosted Redis server. But with these options you won't be able to interact with the service using `heroku redis` commands. Use whatever tooling those providers offer.