# How to check if there is a PostgreSQL backup scheduled?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, backup

I have recently started working on an existing Heroku environment.

How can I tell if there are database backups scheduled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Heroku Postgres, you can [view backup schedules with the following command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#view-backup-schedules):

```
heroku pg:backups:schedules
```

You [might](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55470675/354577) have to provide the `--app` argument so Heroku knows which app you're interested in.